# Fejer Kernel is Unbounded

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fejer-kernel

**Statement:** Given the Fejer Kernel $F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\bigg(\frac{\sin(\frac{nx}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}\bigg)^2$. Show that $F_n(x)$ is unbounded for $x=0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: why don't you just compute the limit as x -> 0? Is that the right expression for the fejer kernel? wikipedia gives something else...

Comment: That's not the Fejer kernel. You're missing some squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big square missing:
$$
F_n(x) = \frac{1}{2n\pi}\left(
\frac{\sin(\frac{nx}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}\right)^2\sim_0 
\frac{1}{2n\pi}\left(
\frac{\frac{nx}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2=\frac n{2\pi}
$$

Comment: How did you get those approximation?

Also could have I used the fact that $F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1-\cos(nx)}{1-\cos(x)}$ and applied L'Hopital's rule twice to see that the limit at 0 is divergent as $n \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: I get them using the fact that $\sin$ has a derivative $=1$ on $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

When $a$ goes to $0$, $\sin(a) \simeq a$. Then replacing each sine by its argument, for $x$ going to $0$, you arrive to
$$F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\bigg(\frac{\sin(\frac{nx}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}\bigg)^2\simeq n$$ If you want to go further, you could use a Taylor expansion built at $x=0$ and obtain
$$F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\bigg(\frac{\sin(\frac{nx}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}\bigg)^2\simeq n-\frac{1}{12} \left (n-1)n(n+1\right) x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$